# How to make an HDMI splitter use full resolution?

Tags: hdmi, splitter

I have one monitor and one TV screen. Both support 1920x1080 when I plug them directly into my graphics card. But when I plug them both into the unpowered HDMI splitter I just bought, that is plugged into the graphics card, they show 640x480.  I can't see any way of changing this in Windows Display Settings or my Radeon Software.

Is this fixable please?  Else can someone explain why this is happening if there is no solution.

Comment: HDMI splitters are "illegal" devices. Use multiple outputs on your graphics card instead.

Comment: My graphics card has only two outputs, and I have three monitors I need to plug in. Please explain what you mean by illegal, or link to something that explains. I purchased this quite legally.

Comment: Whether you can get it to 1080p or not, you will not have "3 displays" from 2 GPU outputs - you will have 2 showing the same screen & one other. An HDMI splitter will send the same picture to both displays. There is no fix for this, other than use a better graphics card with support for more displays.

Comment: Thank you Tetsujin, I know that, and it's not my question.

Comment: 'Illegal' here refers to the HDMI specification, not the law . There's no HDMI police going to knock down your door and seize your illegal HDMI devices

Comment: Thanks Journeyman, but please can someone explain what they mean by illegal? I know nothing about HDMI and wouldn't know where to look in the specification for help

Comment: You need to use a quality HDMI splitter, such as [these](https://www.monoprice.com/search/index?keyword=hdmi+splitter) from MonoPrice _(I use the [BlackBird 4K Pro 1x4](https://www.monoprice.com/product?p_id=21613) and it works flawlessly)_. @DanielB it's not illegal to split HDMI signals, as doing so doesn't remove HDCP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very common problem with HDMI splitters.

Note that HDMI is bidirectional in nature, so in your case you have two
monitors sending back information to the computer, such as the
maximum resolution and more. With the splitter, both devices are sending
conflicting information back, so this might confuse the display driver
and cause it to ignore both and drop down to a low resolution.

If your display adapter software supports it, you might set it to
ignore the monitor's EDID information (which is the information
that the monitor sends back).

You might also be able to set the two monitors to better values
or at least to agree on all values. This depends on the firmware
of the monitors.

I also definitely recommend using a powered HDMI splitter, because
this will not only ensure high-quality copying of the digital signals
but will typically boost that signal as well, reducing the likelihood
of interference due to longer cable lengths. Shorter cables may also
help for better quality.

Comment: Thank you, a friend just recommended a power splitter and it works absolutely fine, no problem, no setup. Got a Volkano powered hub. Three times the price of an unpowered splitter, but still not expensive really.